# Converting Integer time stamp into java date

Tags: java, datetime

I have following time stamp in Integer form

```
1333125342
```

I can convert it using SQL:

```
select DATEADD(ss, FlOOR(1333089223/86400)*86400, '1970-01-01 00:00:00') AS Date
```

How to convert it in java? So that it would return value:

```
3/30/12 12:18:43 PM
```

Comment: what does `1333125342` represent ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi its integer value of timestamp

Comment: doesn't seem likely: `date: invalid date `1333125342'`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming its the time since 1/1/1970 in seconds. you can try

```
String dateAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                          .format(new Date(1333125342 * 1000L));
```

Comment: The `L` represents that the 1000 is a `long` without this you are likely to get an overflow when you multiply an `int` * `int` but an `int` * `long` will result in a `long` which won't overflow.

Comment: 1333125342 * 1000 is 1685480240 (due an overflow) 1333125342 * 1000L is 1333125342000L

Comment: thanks for `1000L` explanation. Any official link for the same?

Comment: @SumitRamteke I would read the source for RollCycle and RollCycles as most of the code is a one liner.

Answer (score 2):

if it is  milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since `January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT`

then simply use

```
new java.util.Date(millis);
```

and if you need it in particular format

```
3/30/12 12:18:43 PM
```

then use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the `Date` to desired formatted `String`

Comment: if not process it accordingly to convert it into such millis

Comment: it return 1970-01-16 15:48:09 but the value is 3/30/12 12:18:43 PM

Comment: You need to know what this number represents, and then see my above comment, You need to multiply with 1000L as peter suggested

Answer (score 0):

That timestamp contains the seconds elapsed since 1970-1-1 0:00 UTC.

To convert it to a Java Date instantiate a new `Date` Object [(see Java doc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and invoke `setTime()` on that. Note, that `setTime` expects milliseconds instead of seconds, so you would have to multiply your timestamp by 1000.

The `toString()` method yields something readable.